# error in if statement while using a iterative element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to use 2 consecutive rows in a single if statement using a iterative 'i' in for loop for dataframe but it shows error in execution. my code is -

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Abhi\\Desktop\\Book1.csv",low_memory=False)

data['DV+']=pd.Series("",index=data.index)

for j in range(len(data.index)):

    if (data['Customer_Site_ID'][j]==data['Customer_Site_ID'][j+1] and (data['DCVolt'][j]-data['DCVolt'][j+1])>0.2 and min(data['BatDC'][j],data['BatDC'][j+1])>0 and (data['BatDC'][j]-data['BatDC'][j+1])<5):
        data['DV+'][j]=1
    else:
        data['DV+'][j]=0
data.to_csv("C:\\Users\\Abhi\\Desktop\\book11.csv", index=False,encoding='utf-8')
```

error i m getting is -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-0469458ba48f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Abhi/Desktop/newfeed.py', wdir='C:/Users/Abhi/Desktop')

  File "C:\Users\Abhi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Abhi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Abhi/Desktop/newfeed.py", line 15, in <module>
    if (data['Customer_Site_ID'][j]==data['Customer_Site_ID'][j+1] and (data['DCVolt'][j]-data['DCVolt'][j+1])>0.2 and min(data['BatDC'][j],data['BatDC'][j+1])>0 and (data['BatDC'][j]-data['BatDC'][j+1])<5):

  File "C:\Users\Abhi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 603, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)

  File "C:\Users\Abhi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 2169, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))

  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 98, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3557)

  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 106, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3240)

  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4279)

  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 404, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:8564)

  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 410, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:8508)

KeyError: 15
```

plz let me know the correct way to access the values of rows in dataframe using iterative element in for(any) loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the pandas (0.20.1) documentation, specifically [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) section on Indexing and Selecting Data.

You can access the values of rows in a dataframe using `.loc`, among other options.

```
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({'column':[i for i in range(15)]})

>>> for i in range(len(data)):
...     print(data.loc[i, 'column'])
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```